# Why python does not replace the new value of a list by iteration?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am wondering why my for loop is not updating the old_hosts values and why is updating the workers in the following code? I am NOT assigning any new value to the workers variable!!!

```
workers = [['w1', 1],['w2',2]]
old_hosts = [['w1',-1],['w1',-11]]

for old_host in old_hosts:
    old_host = [*(worker for worker in workers if worker[0]==old_host[0])][0]
    old_host[1]= 3
    print('old_host: ' + str(old_host))
print('workers: ' + str(workers))
print('old_hosts: ' + str(old_hosts))
```

**output**:

```
old_host: ['w1', 1]
old_host: ['w1', 1]
workers: [['w1', 3], ['w2', 2]]
old_hosts: [['w1', -1], ['w1', -11]]
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to a different topic after valid answers have been posted. You can always post a new question.

Comment: To answer your new question: `old_host` is a reference to the current worker from `workers` list in your loop. When you're changing an element in `old_host` you are changing the original list.

Comment: thank you. how can I detach them from each other, so if old_host gets a copy of the value from workers?

Answer (score 3):

because in `for-loop` you create a local variable and assign your array to a local variable and you don't change your `old_hots` at all.

For changing your array you need `index` and assign what you want to this index. for this purpose I use `enumerate` like below:

```
workers = [['w1', 1],['w2',2]]
old_hosts = [['w1',-1],['w1',-11]]

for idx , old_host in enumerate(old_hosts):
    old_hosts[idx] = [*(worker for worker in workers if worker[0]==old_host[0])][0]
print('workers: ' + str(workers))
print('old_hosts: ' + str(old_hosts))
```

Output:

```
workers: [['w1', 1], ['w2', 2]]
old_hosts: [['w1', 1], ['w1', 1]]
```

Comment: thank you, just I edited the question and am asking why the workers value is changed?

Comment: @MohammadSadeghAslanpour welcome. this question is closing by other. maybe this is better ask another question. if this is correct please read this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Your code was nearly correct. You have to assign to the list element you want to change not the variable. Your solution will break if `old_hosts` contains a worker id that is not in `workers`. I removed the redundant generator expression.

```
workers = [['w1', 1],['w2',2]]
old_hosts = [['w1',-1],['w1',-11]]

for old_host in old_hosts:
    old_host[1] = [worker[1] for worker in workers if worker[0]==old_host[0]][0]
    print('old_host: ' + str(old_host))
print('workers: ' + str(workers))
print('old_hosts: ' + str(old_hosts))
```

Output

```
old_host: ['w1', 1]
old_host: ['w1', 1]
workers: [['w1', 1], ['w2', 2]]
old_hosts: [['w1', 1], ['w1', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print('old_hosts: ' + str(old_hosts))
```

check this last line, change to

```
print('old_hosts: ' + str(old_host))
```

Comment: Please format your code in your answer to make it easier to read.